# Increase the section index titles in UITableView height equal to tableview height

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can we make the index title height nearly equal to tableview height. or custom height.

Please look the default behaviour of index tableview height.

[image]

Comment: I never did that, but maybe you might need to make a small tableView on the side to work as your index title view. That way you can make it custom.

Comment: I think there is no public api to change that, so you would probably need to implement this whole index view and mechanism by yourself or go through the view hierarchy and modify some properties using private api which I would not recommend.